# Are OAuth Access Tokens confidential?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I have a web application which uses OAuth 2.0 to talk to a third-party service. I want both my server and my web app to talk to the authorized service on behalf of the user. I go through the normal authorization steps of doing the redirect, getting the auth code, exchanging it for the access token, all that jazz. Once complete, my server has the access token and can talk to the service. However, I'd like the web app to talk to the service as well so I don't have to route everything through my server.

Can I send the access token to the web app so I can achieve this? Or, is the access token supposed to be kept confidential between my service and the service, never being disclosed to the user, just just like the client secret is?

I've tried to find an answer for this in the spec and various blog posts, but haven't found a definitive answer either way. I know there is an implied auth method for client-side apps which don't involve a server-side component at all. Therefor my initial guess is that I can send the token to the client. I would like to verify this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The token is considered very sensitive information because it allows access to the service. Anyone could issue requests if they had this token.

This is why the token is passed in the Authorization Header, this is why it's highly recommended you make all calls over https, to protect the headers and body information. This is also why it is recommended that the tokens have s short life span so that if one is indeed compromised, it doesn't last for long.

Yes, you can share this token between your own applications and it should work, provided the receiver of the token does not store the IP addresses of the callers as well or has some other check mechanisms in place.

The ideal situation however would be for you to issue a different set of ClientID and Client Secret to each application which requires access.

Don't forget that this is the way the applications identify themselves to the receiver side and it might be important for reporting and analysis purposes.